# Setting values of a Map<string, integer> in java

Tags: java

in array of int

```
Int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

how do I do it with map to add some keys?

like

```
one => 1
two => 2


Map<String, Integer> aMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Comment: Answers to questions like this are just promoting this recent behavior of lazy questions with no effort.

Comment: Yeah. sorry im new to this map and haven't found sample on how to put values on it with out using put.my Map will be set to some values and it will net be updated or change

Comment: any links that would samples on how to set defaults values on Map would be great

Comment: @user3221754 you haven't found any examples not using `put()` because *that's how maps work*. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the `put` method.

```
Map<String, Integer> aMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
aMap.put("one", 1);
aMap.put("two", 2);
```

For immutable maps, consider using Google Guava's [ImmutableMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html)

```
Map<String, Integer> aMap = ImmutableMap.of("one", 1, "two", 2);
```

Comment: is there no other way? like `public static final int[] num = {1,2,3,4,5};`

Comment: No. You cannot provide a preassigned set of keys.